# Querying date in mongodDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB schema like this :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username :{type:String, unique :true},
    name : String,
    firstDate : Date,
    secondDate : Date,
});
```

and in my atlas database, i see the date entry in this format :

```
firstDate : 2021-05-19T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

I have many such documents in MongoDB atlas and I want to query the entries in a particular range.

*For instance, all the firstDate between 1 May and 1 June*. How can I do it?

[I used this format and it says wrong parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UQ3r.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    firstDate: {
        $gt: new Date('2019-09-18')
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir but the following code isnt working and giving a similar error message, "The provided parameters were invalid. Check your query and try again."